# How to add more than 7 lines in the digest section(addLine) of the Inbox style notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I am creating inbox style notification in which i am adding 10 lines in the digest section using inboxstyle.addLine().After 7 lines i can't see the messages and it shows "..." because apparently it has limit of only 7 lines.Can someone tell me how to display all the 10 lines as implemented in Whatsapp?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use custom notification

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-custom-notification-tutorial/